# Cordova Plugin Camera is not working in Devices

Tags: cordova, plugins, camera, device

I have been facing problem with Cordova camera plugin.

It works in Windows Emulator but failing in devices both in Windows and Android.

I have followed all the instructions but not able to figure out the reason of this quitting app.

As there have been lack of updated documentation in both cordova and microsoft websites, what is missing is in mystery now.

I have seen this plugin working fine earlier in May 2015 with 1.1.0-dev version.

please find the following videos where you can see the problems with this plugin.

works in windows emulator.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e17Dhujnm1A&feature=youtu.be

android device failure, not able to record the emulator, but it is also failing there.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y7cQHc3i5Ew&feature=youtu.be

Windows device failure

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LLofT2ghxIs&feature=youtu.be

If you can't access videos, i uploaded as unlisted, let me know.

In Cordova, web site, there are instructions about using platform specific config.xml, are those still valid?

Is this a state management issue? Do we need to code for any state management during navigation for this plugin?

It is not throwing any error, just simply restarts.

Is there any file size limitation with this plugin?

Comment: As I was doubtful, the issue was related to App State Maintenance. Some how it has been poorly maintained in the app. This experience and solution might be useful to others. The issue is closed

Comment: this issue was resolved partially by placing the pause and resume events outside ready event. I am wondering why is this a wrong approach that is making app loose its relevance !!!